# Remove KM on google map distance calculation using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I basically want to remove **KM** next to distance number because I want to calculate fare price and I can't make any calculations. I hope the given example below its understandable and please find the snippet code for HTML and javascript.

**Example**

- Usually, it writes like this: 5 km
- and I want it to be like this: 5

```js
var source, destination;
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

// initialise the location of the map on Chichester in England (ref lat and lng)
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), {
 center: { lat: 50.834697, lng: -0.773792 },
 zoom: 13,
 mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
 new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('travelfrom'));
 new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('travelto'));
 directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'draggable': true });
});

function GetRoute() {
   
 directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

 source = document.getElementById("travelfrom").value;
 destination = document.getElementById("travelto").value;

 var request = {
  origin: source,
  destination: destination,
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
 };

 directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
   directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  }
 });

 //*********DISTANCE AND DURATION**********************//
 var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
 service.getDistanceMatrix({
  origins: [source],
  destinations: [destination],
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
  unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
  avoidHighways: false,
  avoidTolls: false
 }, function (response, status) {

   if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
    var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
   var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.value;
    var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
    
   var price = document.getElementById("price");

   duration = parseFloat(duration / 60).toFixed(2);
   dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
   dvDistance.innerHTML += "Distance: " + distance + "<br />";
    dvDistance.innerHTML += "Time:" + duration + " min";

   

    price.innerHTML = distance * 2.00;
    

  } else {
   alert("Unable to find the distance via road.");
  }
 });
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
       

        <div>
            <div>
                Travel From : <input id="travelfrom" type="text" name="name" value="Chichester, UK" />
                To : <input id="travelto" type="text" name="name" value="Goodwood aerodrone, UK" />
                <input type="button" value="Get Route" onclick="GetRoute()" />

            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
                <div id="dvDistance">
                </div>
                <br />
                <div id="price">
                </div>
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="dvMap" style="min-height:500px"></div>

    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about just removing the "KM" form the string:

```
var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text.toLowerCase().replace(" km", "");
```

If you want to make calculations with the distance, you should also change the variable's type to Number.

```
var distance = parseFloat(
    response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text.toLowerCase().replace(" km", "")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [text property of distance](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions#Distance.text) is a string which can contain a units specifier.

If you want a number, use the [value property of distance](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions#Distance.value) which is a number and is always in meters.

```
var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value/1000;
```

[image: screenshot of result]

**code snippet:**

```js
var source, destination;
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

// initialise the location of the map on Chichester in England (ref lat and lng)
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), {
  center: {
    lat: 50.834697,
    lng: -0.773792
  },
  zoom: 13,
  mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
  new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('travelfrom'));
  new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('travelto'));
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    'draggable': true
  });
});

function GetRoute() {

  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  source = document.getElementById("travelfrom").value;
  destination = document.getElementById("travelto").value;

  var request = {
    origin: source,
    destination: destination,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };

  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });

  //*********DISTANCE AND DURATION**********************//
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: [source],
    destinations: [destination],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  }, function(response, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
      var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value / 1000;
      var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.value;
      var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");

      var price = document.getElementById("price");

      duration = parseFloat(duration / 60).toFixed(2);
      dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
      dvDistance.innerHTML += "Distance: " + distance + "<br />";
      dvDistance.innerHTML += "Time:" + duration + " min";



      price.innerHTML = distance * 2.00;


    } else {
      alert("Unable to find the distance via road.");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="height:100%;">
  <div class="col-md-12" style="height:100%;">
    <div style="height: 130px;">
      <div>
        Travel From : <input id="travelfrom" type="text" name="name" value="Chichester, UK" /> To : <input id="travelto" type="text" name="name" value="Goodwood aerodrone, UK" />
        <input type="button" value="Get Route" onclick="GetRoute()" />

      </div>
      <br />
      <div>
        <div id="dvDistance">
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="price">
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
      </div>

    </div>

    <div id="dvMap" style="height:65%;"></div>

  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk" type="text/javascript"></script>
```